# How to order by 2 columns simultaneously in MySql

Tags: mysql, newrelic

The below queries works fine, but shows errors in New Relic tool.

Error Message:

> MysqlError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY q.display_order, a.display_order ASC' at line 4

SQL Query:

```
SELECT q.question_id,
       a.answer_id, 
       q.question_name, 
       a.option_name, 
       q.display_order AS ques_order,
       a.correct, 
       a.display_order AS opt_order
FROM questions q 
JOIN answers a 
ON (a.question_id = q.question_id) 
WHERE test_id = 24
ORDER BY q.display_order, a.display_order ASC
```

Comment: Try replacing a.display_order with opt_order and q.display_order with     ques_order in your order by clause

Comment: Are you sure it's that query flagging the error?

Comment: I think @Phil is right and that it's either a different query, or the instance New Relic is reporting is missing the `test_id` parameter (and the query is actually a single line, not as formatted in the question).

Comment: I reformatted the question to show the SQL on a single line (as originally posted), since the error references "line 1". If this is the query, you should make sure that the variable passed in for `test_id` is not empty.

Comment: Here is the exact error code from New Relic "MysqlError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY q.display_order, a.display_order ASC' at line 4"

Comment: Which version of mysql?

Comment: Check about the testid, is it in both the table if so add proper table alias to which it belong.

Comment: Thanks everyone. @AshReva I had replaced q.display_order with ques_order and it worked fine.But not sure to how reproduce same error in New Relic.

Comment: @user1965773 should i put my comment in answer and then you can accept? Is it ok? I dont know anything about Relic so sorry about it.